# R implemenation of Closure differs from other functional languages, which makes it behave like imperative language such as C#?

Tags: c#, r, f#, functional-programming, closures

R is a functional language, but it behaves like C# instead of F# in the following case.

in R

```
f <- function() x
x <- 15
f() // prints 15
x <- 20 // shadowing
f() // prints 20
```

in C#

```
int j = 15;
Action<string> funs = x => Console.WriteLine(j);
funs("foo"); // prints 15
j = 20; // mutate
funs("foo"); // prints 20
```

in F#

```
let x = 15
let f y = x
f() // prints 15
let x = 20 // shadowing, to mimic R (purely functional)
f() // prints 15, not 20
```

In R, the example violates my understanding of "**closure closes variables, either by value or by reference**". In C#, closure closes variable by reference. In F#, it doesn't matter as variables are immutable. But in R, it seems closure only closes the symbol name, (certain not by value as it does change; not by reference, since variables are immutable, it is not mutated but shadowed).

So, are there 3 ways that closure closes variables, **by value, by reference, and by name**?

Is there any other functional language behaves like R in this case?

Here, **Dynamic Lookup** as defined in hadley's [book](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functions) seems to explain it a bit, but I couldn't find any other resources that have the term "dynamic lookup".

Comment: Your F# example is wrong.  That isn't assigning a new value to x, it's actually declaring an new variable named x which hides the previous one in the current scope.  If you declare x as mutable and then assign to it using `<-` then it works the same as the C#.

Comment: @mydogisbox that's intended, i am doing shadowing, not assignment in F#, to mimic a purely functional language. BTW, i am not comparing F# to C#, I am comparing F# to R, and C# to R.

Comment: I am uncertain how to answer this without simply quoting R's documentation on its implementation of lexical scoping to you.

Comment: @joran all the 3 languages are lexical scoped

Comment: But just because they all claim to be "lexically scoped" doesn't mean there won't be some small differences in implementation. They may be similar, but they are different languages, after all.

Comment: @joran  I agree, that's the reason I asked about the core differences in the mechanisms which result in the discrepancy.

Comment: It behaves closer to dynamically-scoped variables than lexical closures when comparing the behavior to Common Lisp. I'll have to experiment a bit more with the r runtime before being completely sure on this.

Comment: @ClaytonStanley I agree, but R is lexical scoped.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but perhaps these examples help a bit to illustrate how a value might be scoped (but these probably aren't very good examples!) but I strongly suggest you read the [**evaluation of expressions**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Evaluation-of-expressions) section of the R Language Definition (in fact I should probably go and read it again too):

```
# Define default value for x in function definition
f <- function( x = 15 ) x
f()
#[1] 15

# Assign value to x in .GlobalEnv
x <- 20

# But x is found in the environment of the function call because we already defined it there, so value we assigned inside the function is returned
f()
#[1] 15

# Now we pass an object, x to the function which causes it to search up the calling stack for an 'object' called x
f(x)
#[1] 20

# In this example we use 'get' to search for the object. In the help page it states:
# The default is to search from the current environment of the call to 'get'
f <- function() get( "x" )
f()
[1] 20

# But we can specify an environment to search in
# In this case we specify an environment where x was not defined
# and it is not found
f<- function() { pos <- sys.nframe()+1 ; get("x" ,  envir = as.environment(pos) ) }
f()
#Error in get("x", envir = as.environment(2)) : object 'x' not found
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand how it works. I just feel strange what the closure doesn't bind the value to the variable at definition, like all other functional language do. I had thought it is the "rule" of functional language.

Comment: Sorry, I took your question to mean you needed some illustration. This is a subject I find tough to grasp (and some more knowledgeable persons may point out I have not grasped it). Anyway, it does *bind* the value, but only in the specified environment. It depends on what is evaluated and where it is evaluated. It does make sense. Every object has hidden attributes, one of which is the environment in which the object was created.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from Scheme, I don't see the confusion.

E.g., using chibi-scheme (R7RS):

```
$ chibi-scheme
> (define f (lambda () x))
WARNING: reference to undefined variable: x
> (define x 15)
> (f)
15
> (define x 20)
> (f)
20
```

Should be the same for any compliant Scheme version (works in Guile and MIT/GNU Scheme, at least).
REPLs may differ from compilers, but even if you wrote the above and *compiled* it, it would use a symbol table and resolve the reference after parsing the file. It would still work.

`f` has a reference to the value at the memory location designated by the variable `x`.  When you do `f <- 15` or `f <- 20` you update the *value* and not the reference or location.

I may be wrong (or using technical terms incorrectly), but I still find this to be non-surprising.